Is it possible to hide the untagged test execution from the console output in jest-cucumber library?
Problem Description:
I wanted to hide the untagged test execution from the console output in jest-cucumber library?
Test:
@smoke
Scenario: Successful Login
Given I am on the login page
When I fill in "username" with "test"
And I fill in "password" with "test"
And I click on the "Login" button
Then I should see the "Welcome" page
Scenario: Failed Login
Given I am on the login page
When I fill in "username" with "test"
And I fill in "password" with "wrong password"
And I click on the "Login" button
Then I should see the "Error" page
I am running the tests with tag smoke. The jest-cucumber runner works as expected. I just want to hide the console logs for skipped tests.
Execution command:
user01@12343 my-e2e-tests % NODE_ENV=uat TAG_FILTER='@smoke' jest
Console Log:
 PASS  tests/featureFileLoader.ts Home Page ✓ Successful Login (1249 ms) ○  Failed Login
I would like to hide the execution of Failed Login tests in console logs.
custom-reporter.js
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const originalLog = console.log;

// Modify console.log to only print for tagged scenarios
console.log = (...args) => {
  const currentTest = expect.getState().currentTestName;
  // Check if the current test name contains a tag you want to show logs for
  if (currentTest && (currentTest.includes('@smoke'))) {
    originalLog(...args);
  }
};

setDefaultTimeout(60000);

Tried to retrieves the name of the current test scenario using expect.getState().currentTestName.
It checks if the current test name contains the tag @smoke. If it does, it calls the original console.log to print the logs; otherwise, the logs are suppressed.
This isn't functioning as expected. I would appreciate any insights you might have on this.
